# Nativescript 6.2 - convert base64 image string to imageSource

Tags: nativescript

In my NS 6.2 Core app I am trying to load an image that comes from the backend as a base64 string. This string needs to be converted to an imageSource and displayed in an image element.  I am testing on an Android physical device.

So far I tried:

```js
const img = <Image>e.object;    
let imageSource = new ImageSource();
var isLoaded = imageSource.loadFromBase64('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0i...');
if (isLoaded) {
    img.imageSource = imageSource;
}
```

The base64 string is confirmed to be valid, but isLoaded is always false.
I also tried:

```js
const s: string = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9Im5vIj8...';
imageSource.fromBase64(s).then((loaded:boolean) => {
    img.imageSource = imageSource;
});
```

This did not work either, no errors, just nothing is loaded into the Image.

Last thing I tried was:

```js
import { fromBase64, ImageSource } from "tns-core-modules/image-source";

const s: string = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9Im5vIj8...';
img.imageSource = fromBase64(s);
```

This produces an error:

```html
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Calling js method onCreateView failed
System.err: Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
```

I am out of ideas.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to `split` your base64 string to remove `data:image/svg+xml;base64` part.

```
let base64 = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0i...'
let data = base64.split(",");
let isLoaded = imageSource.loadFromBase64(data[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Jibon, I tried that, but I am still getting false for isLoaded